# Any way to reduce repetitive markup in webpages or something like caching such frequently used markup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you have the same set of buttons on each item row of a long list of items. Is there any way to reduce the markup (of repeated elements on the page)? Any way to make it more efficient ?

Is there any facility to cache that kind of  markup like CSS or js files.  I am looking out for this solution for a web 2.0  site.

## Edit

Not looking for a server side solution, as I am already aware of those. I am bascially concerned about reducing file size of my webpages transferred to user's browser.

Comment: The pages are usually dynamic and lists/tables etc. are generated in code. So repeated elements aren't usually a concern because the server-side code that generates it is not redundant even if the resulting markup is.

Comment: @Kevin : I am trying to understand in what ways I can reduce the markup size of my generated pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:

1. Generate the HTML using a server-side language (PHP, ASP, etc) and use loops to create the repetitive markup
2. Create the markup in Javascript, inserting elements into the DOM via a loop.
3. Use a template to provide the markup, and include the template as many times as needed.